# How can lasso CCA be solved using LARS?

Tags: lasso, sparse, canonical-correlation, lars

According to paper By Sun, Ji an Ye; A Least Squares Formulation for Canonical Correlation Analysis http://www.machinelearning.org/archive/icml2008/papers/270.pdf CCA can be reformulated as a least squares problem, where the L1 penalty can be added, and then it can be solved by LARS (least angle regression) which has a benefit for computing the whole solution path for all levels of regularization for a cost of fitting only one model.

I am bit lost in the math, so how is this possible? Is this true for any solver that can solve linear regression with l1 regularization? And most important, how can I reformulate my CCA problem, so it can be solved with LARS (and therefore for all regularization parameters at once)?